# Implementation called rest on gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, backend, gatsby

I have a question on the code below I have to make a rest call to a router with gatbsy.js to do it I use the code below to click on the form I make the call to the backend server that receives the parameters, the backend server is done in node.js and already use express.js, I have tested routers with postman and an app written for ios by making rest calls and there is no problem whatsoever, how can I go about making the call correctly in gatsby.js?

**Frontend:**

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import server from "./setup.js";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import SEO from "../components/seo";

//Variabile che rappresenta il router per la registrazione al server
var loginaddress=server.server+"/login";

//Pagina di registrazione
const NuovoPage = () => (

  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Registrazione" /> 

    <form method="POST" action={loginaddress}>
    Email:    <input type="text"  name="Email" /> <p></p>
    Password: <input type="password"  name="Password" /> <p></p>
   <br></br>
    <input type="button" value="Registrazione" />
    <p></p>
    </form>
    <Link to="/">Ritorna alla homepage</Link>
  </Layout>
)

//Esporto la pagina della pagina di registrazione
export default NuovoPage
```

**setup.js**

```
var server="http://localhost:8787";

module.exports.server = server;
```

**Backend:**

```
const express = require("express");
const myParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
    app.post("/login", async function (request, response) {

        var ret = 0;
        try {
            console.log("\n" + request.body.Email + " sta cercando di effettuare il login");
            ret = await UserController.Login(request.body.Email, request.body.Password);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Errore: " + ret + "\n err: " + err);
            ret = 0;
        }
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.send(JSON.stringify({
            return: ret
        }));

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to send HTTP request in your React code. [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is the most popular way to do that. [Here](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/#post-requests) is a nice tutorial how to do that:

Your form tag:

```
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            {/* ... */}
          <button type="submit">Registrazione</button>
        </form>
```

HandleSubmit function:

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post(`https://http://localhost:8787/login`, { yourData })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MDN page for [Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

> How an `<input>` works varies considerably depending on the value of its type attribute, hence the different types are covered in their own separate reference pages. If this attribute is not specified, the default type adopted is `text`.
>
> The available types are as follows:
>
> - button: A push button with no default behavior displaying the value of the value attribute, empty by default.
> - submit: A button that submits the form.
> - ...

So if you change your `input` to have a `type` of `submit`, the user agent attempts to submit the form to the server when the click event occurs (typically because the user clicked the button).

```
<form method="POST" action={loginaddress}>
  Email:    <input type="text"  name="Email" />
  Password: <input type="password"  name="Password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Registrazione" />
</form>
```